# Sphinx - Using Multi-cores

Tags: php, sphinx

I know that sphinx supports using multi-cores whilst searching. I wanted to know is this enabled by default or do we have to do something to enable it? If so then how do we enable it and how do I know that its using all cores?

Thanking you

Answer (score 0):

Try searching the Sphinx forum, there are a number of threads about this. For example
http://sphinxsearch.com/forum/view.html?id=7677

There is also a relevent blog post...
http://sphinxsearch.com/blog/2011/10/19/dist_threads-the-new-right-way-to-use-many-cores/